# C++ error: intrinsic function was not declared in scope

Tags: c++, gcc, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I want to compile code that uses the intrinsic function `_mm256_undefined_si256()` (returns a vector of 8 packed double word integers). Here is the reduced snipped of the affected function from the header file:

```
// test.hpp
#include "immintrin.h"

namespace {
    inline __m256i foo(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
        __m256i res = _mm256_undefined_si256();
        // some inline asm stuff
        // __asm__(...);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Compiling via `gcc -march=native -mavx2 -O3 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o app` throws the following error `>>_mm256_undefined_si256<< was not declared in this scope.`

I can not explain why this intrinsic function is not defined, since there are other intrinsics used in the header file which work properly.

Comment: Are you actually compiling C++ code with `gcc`? `g++` should be used instead.

Comment: @Elliott
 Sure, I'm of course aware of that `g++` is `gcc` with some extra options enabled by default. However, I don't see those flags being used in the question, which may cause linker errors, so I doubt if that's actually the command used to compile the code.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki I‘m getting the same error with g++.

Comment: [Your code compiles on the godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ceTesPesb), so it may be something specific to your machine. May you post the full compiler output message?

Comment: Please read how to (and why) provide a [mre].

Comment: @Frank: Actually generating code for a function using `_mm256_undefined_si256()` does fail without `-mavx` (or a `-march=` that includes AVX): https://godbolt.org/z/dGq4EKao5 .  But you're right, with it inside an unused `inline` function, GCC only warns about AVX return without AVX enabled changing the ABI.  Only if you comment out the `inline` and `namespace` parts to make it a global definition does GCC actually error on this example.  (But they are passing `-mavx2` which includes `-mavx`, so it should compile on any machine with a new enough GCC.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in GCC4.9 and newer (https://godbolt.org/z/bajMsKvK9).  GCC4.9 was released in April 2014, close to a decade ago, and the most recent release of GCC4.8.5 was in June 2015.  So it's about time to upgrade your compiler!

GCC4.8 was missing that intrinsic, and didn't even know about `-march=sandybridge` (let alone tuning options for Haswell which had AVX2), although it did know about the less meaningful `-march=corei7-avx`.

---

It does happen that GCC misses some of the more obscure intrinsics that Intel adds along with support for a new instruction set, so support for `_mm256_add_epi32` won't always imply `_mm256_undefined_si256()`.

e.g. it took until GCC11 for them to add `_mm_load_si32(void*)` unaligned aliasing-safe `movd` (which I think Intel introduced around the same time as AVX-512 stuff), so that's multiple years late.  (And until GCC12 / 11.3 for GCC to implement it correctly, [<s>Bug 99754</s>](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99754), and still not aliasing-safe for `_mm_load_ss(float*)` ([Bug 84508](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84508)).

But fortunately for the `_mm256_undefined_si256`, it's supported by non-ancient versions of all the mainstream compilers.